# Formally confirm a formula for a certain three-dimensional constrained integral over the unit cube

Tags: pr.probability, mp.mathematical-physics, integration, quantum-mechanics, integer-sequences

The result of the three-dimensional constrained integration (for the Hilbert-Schmidt two-qubit absolute separability probability) over the unit cube $[0,1]^3$
\begin{equation} \label{one}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 9081072000 \left(\lambda _1-\lambda _2\right){}^2 \left(\lambda _1-\lambda _3\right){}^2
   \left(\lambda _2-\lambda _3\right){}^2 \left(2 \lambda _1+\lambda _2+\lambda
   _3-1\right){}^2 \left(\lambda _1+2 \lambda _2+\lambda _3-1\right){}^2 \left(\lambda
   _1+\lambda _2+2 \lambda _3-1\right){}^2 \text{Boole}\left[\lambda _1>\lambda _2\land
   \lambda _2>\lambda _3\land \lambda _3>-\lambda _1-\lambda _2-\lambda _3+1\land \lambda
   _1-\lambda _3<2 \sqrt{\lambda _2 \left(-\lambda _1-\lambda _2-\lambda
   _3+1\right)}\right] \mbox{d} \lambda_3 \mbox{d} \lambda_2 \mbox{d} \lambda_1 
\end{equation}
can be expressed ([QuantumComputing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/13749/give-an-explicit-derivation-of-the-formula-for-the-two-qubit-absolute-separabili)) as
\begin{equation} \label{HSabs}
 \frac{29902415923}{497664}+\frac{-3217542976+5120883075 \pi -16386825840 \tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}{32768 \sqrt{2}} =
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{32(29902415923 - 24433216974 \sqrt{2})+248874917445 \sqrt{2}(5  \pi - 16  \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right))}{2^{16} \cdot 3^5} \approx 0.00365826.
\end{equation}

Can a formal derivation of this result be given (yielding possibly  a
re-expressed formula of interest)?

As a Mathematica question,

[MathematicaFormulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral)

this seems quite daunting (very large intermediate outputs). Some simple attempts at transformation of variables did not seem initially productive.

Some ten years ago,

[2009paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0393044008001381)

I obtained this result (eq. (34) there), but the now-requested formalized step-by-step process was not detailed.
Comments of present interest there were that `[C]opious use was made of trigonometric identities involving the tetrahedral dihedral angle $\phi=\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$, assisted by V. Jovovic" and that use was made of the Sloane website sequence
A025172--"Let phi = arccos(1/3), the dihedral angle of the regular tetrahedron. Then cos(n*phi) = a(n)/3^n".
(This sequence is "[u]sed when showing that the regular simplex is not "scisssors-dissectable" to a cube, thus answering Hilbert's third problem.".)

[A025172sequence](https://oeis.org/A025172)

These comments led me to consult my email archives.

On April 21, 2008 I wrote to Vladeta Jovovic (and also Wouter Meeussen and Neil Sloane) the following:

"Dear Drs. Jovocic/Meeussen/Sloane:

I been doing some analyses in which I've been able to simplify several
trigonometric terms using the relation

cos(n*phi) =a(n)/3^n

where

phi=ArcCos(1/3)

reported in Sloane's Superseeker sequence

A025172.

I have two further terms

ArcTan[(1/329 )(729 - 460 Sqrt[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral))]

and

ArcTan[(1/7) (9 + 4 Sqrt[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral))],

which also clearly pertain, since

329/729 =a(6)/3^6

and

-7/9 =a(2)/3^2.

But I don't see how to manipulate them to reexpress/simplify them in terms of phi, which I presume is possible/natural.

Perhaps you have some insights in this matter?

Sincerely,

Paul B. Slater

P. S. I also have the term

ArcTan[(1/7) (-3 + Sqrt[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral))]

which perhaps also has some simpler form."

I received replies:

"for n from 0 to 10 do q:=tan(-n*phi):print(expand(q));od:

```
                            0


                             1/2
                         -2 2


                             1/2
                          4 2
                          ------
                            7


                              1/2
                          10 2
                        - -------
                            23


                             1/2
                         56 2
                         -------
                           17


                             1/2
                         22 2
                         -------
                           241


                               1/2
                          460 2
                        - --------
                            329


                              1/2
                        1118 2
                        ---------
                          1511


                               1/2
                         1904 2
                       - ---------
                           5983


                               1/2
                        13870 2
                        ----------
                           1633


                               1/2
                        10604 2
                        ----------
                          57113
```

V.

"

and

"
phi=ArcCos(1/3)

ArcTan[(1/329 )(729 - 460 Sqrt[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral))]

= 5*Pi/4 - 3*phi

ArcTan[(1/7) (9 + 4 Sqrt[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral))],

= 3*Pi/4 - phi.

Best regards,
Vladeta"

Within the next week, V. Jovovic also wrote:

"
ArcTan[(1/7) (-9 + 4 Sqrt[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral))]

= Pi/4-phi

ArcTan[(1/7) (-3 + Sqrt[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral))]

= Pi/8-phi/2
"

"
ArcSin[(1/6) (4 + Sqrt[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral))]
= 3*Pi/4 - phi
"

and

"
ArcCsc[3/17 Sqrt[52 + 14 Sqrt[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral)]]

= 5*Pi/8-phi

ArcTan[7/(3 + Sqrt[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral))]

= Pi/8+phi/2

ArcTan[1/(3 + Sqrt[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral))]

= - Pi/8+phi/2

ArcCsc[Sqrt[6 (2 + Sqrt[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral))]]

= 5*Pi/8-phi

"

Although this email correspondence was clearly central to the obtaining of the indicated formula (for which a formalized proof is requested) it is presently not clear to me in what manner they were employed.

Nicolas Tessore has now shown that the 3D-constrained integral that is the subject of this question can be converted, using the transformation,
\begin{equation}
\left\{\lambda _1\to \frac{x}{2 x+1},\lambda _2\to \frac{(x+1) y}{(2 x+1) (y+1)},\lambda
   _3\to \frac{(x+1) z}{(2 x+1) (y+1)}\right\}
\end{equation}
to an unconstrained form,
\begin{equation}
\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \int_z^{-z+2 \sqrt{1-z}+2} \int_y^{2 \sqrt{-\frac{y^3 z+2 y^2 z-y^3-2 y^2+y z-y}{(y+z-1)^4}}+\frac{-3 y z+4
   y-z^2+z}{(y+z-1)^2}} S \hspace{.1in} \mbox{d} z  \mbox{d} y \mbox{d} x,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
S =
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
9081072000 (x+1)^8 (1-2 z)^2 (x-y)^2 (y-z)^2 (y+z-1)^2 (x (-y+z-1)+z)^2 (x
   (y+z)+z-1)^2
\end{equation}
divided by
\begin{equation}
(2 x+1)^{16} (y+1)^{15}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Some very interesting supportive Mathematica analyses of the problem/answer have been given by the user "JimB" in the update to his answer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral .

Answer (score 1):

A highly skillful analysis in Mathematica of the problem has been given by the user "JimB" in his answer to

[MathematicaFormulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral)  .

That analysis was based on a transformation by Nicolas Tessore of the original 3D constrained integration problem to an unconstrained one.

The  answer given by JimB
\begin{equation}
\frac{29902415923}{497664}-\frac{50274109}{512 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{3072529845 \pi }{32768
   \sqrt{2}}+\frac{1024176615 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{4096 \sqrt{2}}
\end{equation}
or in Mathematica notation,

```
29902415923/497664 - 50274109/(512 Sqrt[2]) - (3072529845 π)/(32768 Sqrt[2]) +(1024176615 ArcCos[1/3])/(4096 Sqrt[2])
```

fully agrees with the earlier (2009) set of results-shown in the question statement.